# How to get the content of an element at the same level of one element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

this is my HTML file :

```
<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" style="top: 703px; bottom: -791px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%;">
    <div class="fc-content">
        <div class="fc-time" data-start="4:00" data full="4:00 PM">
            <span>4:00</span>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="fc-title">Work Order 1003</div>
    <div class="fc-bg"></div>
    <div class="fc-resizer"></div>
</a>
```

How can I get this div content `<div class="fc-title">Work Order 1003</div>` when pressing on this div `<div class="fc-bg"></div>`?

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.fc-title')`

Comment: [.siblings() | jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: But how i can get the siblings text ? i used .text() and it didn't work.

Comment: When `.text()` isn't an option, you can use `.html()` instead.

Comment: You might need to refer to `event delegation` also, if your markup is changing dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say your html changes dynamically it could be possible that you have to use [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.fc-bg', function(event){ //delegate the event to the document

    event.preventDefault(); //prevent possible side-effects with a-tag if needed

    var text = $(this).siblings('.fc-title').text();

    $('#result').text(text);
});
```

Note: It is recomment to use the neares static parent for event-delegation, so you can use

`$('a.fc-time-grid-event').on('click', '.fc-bg',function(event){})`

as long as the link does not get generated dynamically.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/300cd02a/)

Comment: @WissemAchour as you can see in the Demo, with the provided Markup the text of this div gets displayed. There must be another issue in your code.You can update your question with the code you are trying right now

Comment: Just i have this single line 
'$(document).on('click', '.fc-bg', function(e) { event.preventDefault();var text = $(this).siblings('.fc-title').text();alert($('#result').text(text));openPopUpWindow(e);});

Comment: @WissemAchour you are alerting a jQuery-Object which is returned by the `.text()`-function, see the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/btny2pmb/1/) here

Comment: Thank you , but still not working for me but as i can see it works well in your demo, I will try to find out why it's not working for me and I will share with you the news.

Comment: I found the issue, sometimes the title goes under the 'fc-content' so i use this line now '$(this).siblings('.fc-content').children(".fc-title")' and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

as `.fc-title` is immediate previous sibling of clicked element, you can use `.prev()` selector:

```
$('body').on('click','.fc-bg',function(){
  alert($(this).prev().text());
});
```

or `.siblings(".fc-title")`

```
$('body').on('click','.fc-bg',function(){
  alert($(this).siblings(".fc-title").text());
});
```

Comment: no my html changes dynamically in my project and i need to get a specific sibling text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.prev('div')` jQuery function to select immediate previous div of clicked `.fc-bg` class.

```
$(document).on("click",".fc-bg",function(){
    alert($(this).prev("div").text());
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("click",".fc-bg",function(){
    alert($(this).siblings(".fc-title").text());
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/drmvbh6k/2/)**

Comment: I want to get a specific prev div because my html changes dynamically.

Comment: Using `siblings()` you can achieve your goal. Check updated answer and demo